# check if any devices on windows are playing sound python

Tags: python, windows, pyaudio

I'm trying to detect system sounds on windows and I figured I could use the pyaudio module since winrt didn't work for me.
I've got this code that lists all the devices, and I know I can open streams with pyaudio

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    print(dev)
```

but how can I tell whether any of these devices are currently outputting sound?    Do I open a stream for each one and take the mean square root of the bytes?  If this is an XY problem and I'd be better off using another module, please let me know

Comment: Checking the audio stream sounds right to me but I would just check that they were non-zero rather than looking at the mean square root...

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python I didn't find any very effective module to retrieve the internal audio of a pc, rather I found a way to simulate the output devices as Input using **Stereo Mixer** on windows platform.

First enable **Stereo Mixer** on your windows environment.

After that find the index on which the stereo mixer is located using this code :

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    print("\n\n Index " + str(i) + " :\n")
    dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    print(dev.get('name'))
    print("------------------------------------------------------------")
```

This code will list all the audio devices along with their indexes. Note the index of Stereo Mixer in your pc.

Here comes the main code to detect sound, replace the device variable's value with the index of Stereo Mixer. For me it was 2.

```
import pyaudio
import audioop

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100
silent_threshold = 1

device = 2
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels = p.get_device_info_by_index(device).get('maxInputChannels') , rate=RATE, input = True ,  frames_per_buffer=CHUNK , input_device_index = device)

while True:
    
    data=stream.read(CHUNK)
    threshold = audioop.max(data , 2)
    print(threshold)
    if  threshold > silent_threshold :
        print("Sound found at index " + str(device))
    else :
        print("Sound not found at index " + str(device))

p.terminate()
```

Note the use of silent_threshold, the more you increase its value the less reactive it becomes. For example if you want to detect absolute silence use 1 or to detect quietness use 20 , it depends upon your sound playback on your pc.

Comment: when I run this code, it constantly prints that sound is playing, even though nothing is outputting sound.  the problem I'm looking to solve is detecting whether the computer is producing sound, but the way it's giving false positives when i'm not playing any sound makes me think this is detecting microphone input or something

Comment: It is because you have not set the silent threshold correctly.

Comment: Please tell me the what number is printed when you are not playing any sound during code runtime ?

Comment: it goes back and forth between 3 and 4, and it doesn't change whether I'm playing sound through my headphones or not

Comment: Is stereo mixer enabled correctly ?

Comment: Stereo Mixer is enabled, yeah.  I just changed the threshold to 100 and it works now, so you were right about it being a threshold thing

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before with a library called PyCaw (Python Core Audio for Windows)

first `pip install pycaw`
For some reason this install would only work when running as administrator, but that could be an issue specific to my machine

The following will list the processes currently outputting audio.

```
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities

sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()

for session in sessions:
    print(session.Process)
```

for  some reason it  seems to always have a None reference at the end, but  you should be able to deal with that pretty easily

Comment: https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw is the repo if you want to take a look

Comment: this outputs sessions that aren't outputting sound but could, like discord with a voice channel i'm not in, or chrome with a youtube video I have paused.  I'm trying to tell whether any sound is coming out of a device on the computer (which includes system sound), not just which processes are producing it

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do it.

```
import time
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities

def is_audio_playing():
    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
    for session in sessions:
        if session.State == 1:  # State == 1 means the audio session is active
            return True
    return False

while True:
    if is_audio_playing():
        print("Audio is currently playing.")
    else:
        print("No audio is playing.")
    time.sleep(1)
```