# Is there a way to detect when a program is reproducing a sound in Python

Tags: python, windows, audio, spotify

I’m coding a program that can manage the music's status on my local Spotify [Windows], E.G.: Auto play the music when nothing is reproducing on the computer after some seconds or auto-pause when another program - like, google chrome when I start a video in Youtube - is producing any sound on my computer.

**I don’t know how to detect if a specific program is producing any sound**. I'm working in Python3 but I'm ok if I have to use another library from another language if it already exists.

I also tried some Python libraries like pycaw. As was suggested in this question:
[check if any devices on windows are playing sound python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407319/check-if-any-devices-on-windows-are-playing-sound-python)

But it doesn't really help me. Because it only gives me the info about if a running process reproduced a sound in the past... and I need it in real time.

Here is the closest approach I get

```
excluded_process_name = "Spotify.exe"  # Process name to exclude
def is_sound_playing():
sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
for session in sessions:
    volume = session._ctl.QueryInterface(ISimpleAudioVolume)
    if session.Process and session.Process.name() != excluded_process_name:
        print(session.Process.name())
        if volume.GetMasterVolume() > 0 and psutil.pid_exists(session.Process.pid) and psutil.Process(session.Process.pid).cpu_percent() > 0:
            print(volume.GetMasterVolume())
            return True
```

If I start a video on Youtube, for example, it works. But when I stop the video, "volume.GetMasterVolume()" = 1.0 during a few minutes. After approx. 3 or 5 minutes is 0 again until I resume the video

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: That is an operating-system thing.  So, if there is anyway to check it from the OS, Python can do it - but I don't know if it is possible in a machine with an uncontrolled install. If you have control over the install, there are probably audio-driver proxies that would allow this functionality (so, the OS uses a software based sound-card for all apps).Then, that driver should have its own API's to allow external polling/control

Comment: You may check the https://github.com/jaredsohn/mutefm application, it still works.

Comment: Thanks, @Arek. I checked the application you share and it still working :)